# Consolidate 2 Aggregate Queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is there anyway to combine the 2 queries below without temp tables, nested subqueries, etc?

```
--THE DATA:

ID   Value    CreateDT    UpdateDT
--------------------------------------
1    A        1/20/2023   1/21/2023
2    A        1/15/2023   1/26/2023
3    A        1/1/2023    1/2/2023
4    B        3/1/2023    3/8/2023 
5    C        2/10/2023   2/23/2023
6    C        2/20/2023   2/21/2023
7    C        2/1/2023    2/8/2023
8    D        4/1/2023    4/8/2023 

--WHAT I HAVE SO FAR:

--Query 1
SELECT Value, MAX(CreateDT) CreateDT
FROM SampleTbl
WHERE Value IN (A, X)
GROUP BY Value

--Query 2
SELECT Value, MAX(UpdateDT) UpdateDT
FROM SampleTbl
WHERE Value IN (C, Y)
GROUP BY Value

    
--DESIRED RESULT:

Value    CreateDT     UpdateDT
--------------------------------------
A        1/20/2023     1/26/2023
C        2/20/2023     2/23/2023
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oops, sorry Stu, I forgot to include the WHERE clause for the 2 queries. I updated the question - Apologies!

Comment: I answered based on your question at the time; you can still use both expressions but with a case expression based on your filtering criteria, i'm sure someone will suggest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use both aggregate expressions

```
SELECT Value, MAX(CreateDT) CreateDT, MAX(UpdateDT) UpdateDT from...
```

Answer (score 2):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Value, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN Value IN ('A', 'X') THEN CreateDT END) CreateDT,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Value IN ('C', 'Y') THEN UpdateDT END) UpdateDT
FROM SampleTbl
WHERE Value IN ('A','C','X','Y')
GROUP BY Value
```

If A,C,X,Y are the only possible values, you can omit the final `WHERE` clause.

**Output**:

| Value | CreateDT | UpdateDT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2023-01-20 | null |
| C | null | 2023-02-23 |

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cwmxndDD).

Comment: oh wow, simple once I see it *face palm* - this is what i needed. Thanks dude

Comment: @Losbear This is a wrong answer, the correction of this answer is Stu's one. You should accept that one. Unless the expected output you shared in your post is different with respect to what you're looking for.

Comment: The actual query I'm working on is much more complicated than the sample I provided, and the CASE WHEN inside the MAX() is what I was missing to get the values I was expecting.

Comment: Glad this answer was much helpful to you nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` then apply the conditional aggregation using `case` clause :

```
select Value, MAX(case when desired_date = 'CreateDT' then max_date end) as 'CreateDT',
              MAX(case when desired_date = 'UpdateDT' then max_date end) as 'UpdateDT'
from (
  SELECT 'CreateDT' as desired_date, Value, MAX(CreateDT) max_date
  FROM SampleTbl
  GROUP BY Value
  union all
  SELECT 'UpdateDT' as desired_date, Value, MAX(UpdateDT) max_date
  FROM SampleTbl
  GROUP BY Value
) as s
group by Value
```

Comment: Yea, that's what I have right now - because the queries are so close, I was hoping there was a way to do it without subqueries (or unions)